# Golang calling Windows DLL function with more than 18 arguments

Tags: go, system-calls, dllimport, ffi

I have an external 64 bit .DLL and I have to pass 22 arguments to one of the functions.
Go (go1.16.4 windows/amd64) allows up to 18 arguments. Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say you could try to copy whatever code Go has in `src/runtime/syscall_windows.go` from `Syscall18` to `Syscall20` and see what happens. Still, I'd ask on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) as AFAIK neither core team members reads the `go` tag here on SO. (If you do that, please add the link to your post here as a comment—I'd like to follow.)

Comment: I've tried to make Syscall22 in dll_windows.go, link it with syscall_Syscall22 in src/runtime/syscall_windows.go and rebuilt: go install -a runtime. But it give me errors when trying to call the function

Comment: I've asked in golang-nuts group also: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/C0iAXvHLTEU/m/wdOALPOEDAAJ

Comment: If someone is interested in this issue I made a proposal, as advised: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46552